# Reading and writing to text files on Samsung Galaxy S sd card

Tags: android, sd-card, galaxy

I am thinking that this must not be a very difficult task to achieve and i have managed it with the HTC Desire but for some reason I cannot read from the Samsung Galaxy S SD card in my android application.

I use :

```
public String writeFile1(String text) {

    File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

    File myFile = new File(sdDir+"/TextFiles/patientDetails.txt");
    try{
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.write(text);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        return "success";
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

and this works fine! The file content gets saved and i am very happy. However, when I do the reverse using...

```
//
               File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+fileName);

           FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);

           BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));

           String readString = new String(); 

           //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
           String s = "";
           while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
               s+=readString;   
           }
           return s;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e){

           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I receive a file not found exception! I just wrote to it and can see what I wrote when I mount the SD Card.

Does someone know the solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, could you `Log.d(f.toString())` in your reading method?

Comment: File myFile = new File(sdDir+"/TextFiles/patientDetails.txt"); is this same path you are using for reading file File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+fileName);
? Be sure for it. So, I think fileName="/TextFiles/patientDetails.txt", right?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong constructor you should use

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "filename");
```

instead of

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+fileName);
```

Now your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What happen when you initializing your file object like this

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+fileName
```

in this what happen first you getting the path like this way

```
/sdcard
```

and concatenate with the file name then you getting the result this way

```
filename = "test.txt";

path > /sdcardtext.txt
```

now check that this file didn't found so beware check the complete path for file object.

next thing you can use like this way

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "filename");
```

Comment: Ok, I think I found a solution - for some reason I had to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() this ensured that it searched the mnt\sdcard\text.txt folder which is where the Samsung Galaxy S likes to store the files and not just sdcard\text.txt which is where the HTC Desire stores the files.